# Server Error in '/' Application using Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, database-migration

The problem is that the web page was not deployed after migrating using another computer and also, the migration file was deleted.

the error was

> The model backing the 'ProjectContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing
>   the 'ProjectContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

is there any way to solve this problem from my computer? or there is another problem behind this?

Answer (score 1):

What the message says is that your database model is out of sync with your Entity Framework 'Code First' model / code.

To overcome this issue, you can use [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx). The linked tutorial on MSDN explains what you should do. You effectively have to use the Package Console and some C# code to migrate one version to another. This is something you have to do while coding the project. If you release it, the code can automatically update your database model to match your Entity Framework Code First code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it first!